# Создание рисунка с помощью таблиц HTML

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно повторить этот рисунок использовая таблицы HTML. Единственное что знаю, что это таблина 7x7. Сидел над кодом около двух часов, ничего не получается. То ли я инвалид, то ли сани не едут. Кому не сложно, помогите.

Comment: Ну и где же код ваших попыток?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код таблицы, к которой удалось прийти. Из вопроса не совсем понятно, что именно вызвало у вас трудности.

Comment: не нужно дублировать один и тот же вопрос, достаточно отредактировать существующий, добавив необходимую информацию